# Create output file names based on input file name with autonumbers shell script linux

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, batch-rename

I need to automate a process using a script and generate output files similar to the name of the input files but with some additions to it.

my process is a Java code. two input arguments and two output arguments.

java #process_class# abc.txt abd.txt abc.1.out abd.a.out

If i want to iterate this for the set of text files in my folder how can i do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the files a.txt, b.txt, and c.txt in the directory in which this is run, this program will output a_2.txt, b_2.txt, and c_2.txt with foo appended to each (replace the foo line with your processing commands).

```
for f in *.txt;
    do f2=${f%.*}_2.txt;
    cp $f $f2;
    echo "Processing $f2 file...";
    echo "foo" >> $f2; # Your processing command here
done
```

Comment: thank you sir. my process is a Java code. two input arguments and two output arguments.
java <process> abc.txt abd.txt abc.1.out abc.a.out
If i want to iterate this for the set of text files in my folder how can i do this

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean so I can help you out? Do you want to run the java process on every file in the directory? Can you type out a few of the iterations?

Comment: yea. My folder has twenty text files. a1,a2 to a10 and b1,b2 to b10. my java program takes each of a files and b files and generates output.
Iter1: input: a1.txt, b1.txt 
       output: a1.processed.1.txt, b1.processed.1.txt 
Iter2: Input a2.txt, b2.txt 
       Output: a2.processed.2.txt, b2.processed.2.txt 
This has to go on for all twenty files, that is ten iterations. This is given to a java program as java #program# a1.txt b1.txt a1.processed.1.txt b1.processed.1.txt. Instead of running this java script individually, i am iterating it using a script. (contd;)

Comment: for entry in `ls a*.txt`;do
    for extry1 `ls b*.txt`;do
         java #process# $entry $entry1 <automated output file names>  
                       <automated output file names> 
   done 
done

In the place of <>s i need to automate the file names

Comment: `for num in $(seq 1 10);
do java program a$num.txt b$num.txt a$num.processed.$num.txt b$num.processed.$num.txt;
done;`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was of so much help. Just another quick question. How can i just extract the file name without the extension?

Comment: If `$file` stores the name of a file, including the extension, `${file%.*}` will return only the filename.

Comment: Can u also help me with this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097098/using-two-variables-in-a-loop-to-access-two-diff-file-types-in-the-same-folder-s

Answer (score 0):

```
VAR="INPUTFILENAME"
# One solution this does not use the VAR:
touch INPUTFILENAME{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
# Another
for i in `seq 1 20` ; do
  touch "${VAR}${i}"
done
```

And there are several other ways.

Comment: thank you sir. my process is a Java code. two input arguments and two output arguments.
java <process> abc.txt abd.txt abc.1.out abc.a.out
If i want to iterate this for the set of text files in my folder how can i do this