# Using two variables in a loop to access two diff file types in the same folder shell scripting linux

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I am trying to call two diff files types in a loop.

I have a1.in-a10.in files and b1.out-b10.out files. 
I wanna access both files simultaneously. I dont want to use nested loops but simultaneously.

```
for f1,f2 `ls *.in` `ls *.out`;do
echo "$f1 $f2"
done
```

I get f1 and f2 not valid identified error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can process this with essentially the same command as you did with your last question. Just remove the extra arguments and the Java command.

```
for num in $(seq 1 10);
    do echo a$num.in b$num.out; # processing command here
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is this (here assuming bash):

```
$ touch a{1..10}.in b{1..10}.in

$ ls
a10.in  a2.in  a4.in  a6.in  a8.in  b10.in  b2.in  b4.in  b6.in  b8.in
a1.in   a3.in  a5.in  a7.in  a9.in  b1.in   b3.in  b5.in  b7.in  b9.in

$ for i in {1..10}; do echo a$i.in b$i.in; done
a1.in b1.in
a2.in b2.in
a3.in b3.in
a4.in b4.in
a5.in b5.in
a6.in b6.in
a7.in b7.in
a8.in b8.in
a9.in b9.in
a10.in b10.in
```

Here I'm just echoing the strings but you can use any command you like, `diff`, `cat`, etc instead of `echo`